# google tag manager, where to download binary container for android?

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/ 
says to download binary container.

I only see json version in my google tag manager console.

Comment: Possibly helpful SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347737/tag-manager-how-to-load-binary-default-container

Comment: @nyuen that was closest I found so far as well. But I can't even download a binary version at the moment with the current gtm web console..

Answer (score 1):

Try navigating to Versions > find your version > Actions > Download

Comment: Under Admin > Container Settings, does your container say "Web" or "Android"? If it is a Web container, it will not have the download option. If it is an Android container, it will have the download option.

Comment: oh. mine is web, that's why! I have a hybrid app. So I have to make both web and android for hybrid apps? (there are events that are native to "native" if that make sense, like clicking push notification)

Answer (score 1):

If you end up with a json file, it may be because you're not using GTM **Legacy Android** but the **Firebase(Android)** version of the SDK.
The choice has been given to you when you created the container : [image: GTM setup]

I hope this helps !

Comment: This tip saved me after two days suffering!